# Spring Boot/Security is not redirecting to Okta logout URL - OpenID Connect Logout Options with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, logout, okta

**Description:**
I tried Logout sample application as given in blog: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/03/27/spring-oidc-logout-options, it is working as expected.

But with the same configurations, we are unable to logout from Okta in our main/ organizations’ Application.

**Expected Flow:**

1. On logout button click, UI calls ‘…/testbootapp/logout’ → Spring Security by default handles logout [Spring Boot logout](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/logout.html)
2. ‘**OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler**’ is configured in SpringBoot application, this should redirect to [enter link description here](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#logout)

> **--- Here, in our application Spring Security is not redirecting to Okta logout URL**

**Implementation Details:**

- Spring boot dependency version: 2.7.0
- application.properties is same as defined in blog
- Attached SecurityConfiguration class as used in our application:
  [SecurityConfiguration.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9PJx.png)

---

After enabling spring security logs in our application, we saw that **‘o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy’ does not generate Okta logout URL, instead redirects to root URL**

Extracted Logs from our Application:
*Jul 21 2022 12:47:16 PM IST DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.l.SecurityContextLogoutHandler -Invalidated session 280BDF27CFF81149D6C829EF2ADAC9DF
Jul 21 2022 12:47:16 PM IST DEBUG o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy -Redirecting to /testbootapp/*

Extracted Logs from Sample application given in blog:
*2022-07-21 11:25:20.230 DEBUG 7382 — [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.a.l.SecurityContextLogoutHandler : Invalidating session: C54C40030C14B14F9F03250B769D2E99
2022-07-21 11:25:20.231 DEBUG 7382 — [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy : Redirecting to ‘https://dev-.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/logout?id_token_hint=&post_logout_redirect_uri=https://twitter.com/’*

Answer (score 0):

Add the the below attribute in the `ClientRegistration` :

```
.providerConfigurationMetadata(Map.of("end_session_endpoint","{idc url}/oauth2/v1/logout"))
```

That would hit server and do the complete logout.